# How to wrap text with an element where you don't have control over markup?

Tags: jquery

So I'm working on a feature where I don't have control over the markup. I want to add padding to some text but the problem is that it doesn't have a container element that I can target. If I target the .content-header and add padding it pads all the content within that div which is not what I want. Markup looks like this. How can I wrap the text with a `<p>` element?

```
<div class="content-header">
  <div class="element"><img src="img.png"></div>
  "Text that I want to wrap in an element"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter a text (nodeType=3) and then wrap it in a p tag.
See below:

```js
$('.content-header').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrapAll("<p class='red' />");
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-header">
  <div class="element"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UgUs.jpg?s=32&g=1"></div>
  "Text that I want to wrap in an element"
  <span>Another text in span</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all nodes; then, [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the *non-empty* text nodes and wrap that:

```
$('.content-header')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    // we're only interested in text nodes that are not empty
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
  })
  .wrap('<p>');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hilakokapa/1/)